# Positive semi-definite Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume that we have a positive semi-definite matrix A. Can we decompose it as follows,

$$A= U^T U \quad ?$$

Or is it only feasible for a positive definite matrix?

Comment: A *symmetric* positive semidefinite matrix? Because your right-hand side is symmetric, so your left hand side should be too.

Comment: So this decomposition is applicable for both positive semidefinite and positive definite?

Comment: Also: What are your thoughts? Have you looked at the proof for the positive-definite case and asked what parts might/might not carry through to the semidefinite case? If so, you can add these to your question by clicking "edge" just beneath the question. And if you don't, your question's likely to be closed...

Comment: "So this decomposition is applicable for both positive semidefinite and positive definite?" Why would you think that my question in any way suggested this?

Comment: 1. The difference that I am familiar with is that eigenvalues for a positive semidefinite can be 0. 

2. I did not assume that you suggested this. But I would appreciate an explanation.

Comment: see algorithm http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every positive semidefinite matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ have a unique square root, ie there exists unique $C\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that $A=C^2$. The square root $C$ is symmetric, thus $U=C$ will do the job.
Conversely, if the matrix $A$ is not symmetric, there can not exist such a decomposition: because matrices of the form $U^TU$ are symmetric.

Comment: Your explanation gave me insight into what I was missing. Positive semidefinite matrices are by definition symmetric; therefore, such matrices can be decomposed into U transpose times U.